# Replace a Core Data error message

Tags: core-data, error-handling, message

I have distributed test versions of a Core Data document-based application among various beta-testers, and of course, because of the frequent change of model, some of them (and even me) have found themselves in front of the criptic "The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store", which is poorly translated in french (le modèle d'objet géré etc.).

I was wondering if there was a possibility to substitute this message by a more explicit string, like "This document was created or modified by a newer version of the application and cannot be opened", which could be localized.

Is there an example of NSPersistantDocument subclass (or application delegate) available somewhere? I googled a lot and found nothing.

Where is the best place to insert this code ?

Thanks!

Comment: Implement `willPresentError:`? See [Handling Received Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/HandleReceivedError/HandleReceivedError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH205-BAJEHAJC)

Comment: willPresentError is not called by NSPersistentDocument. It should, but is not. appDelegate's willPresentError get called, but too late, the Core Data error is already fired. I can do something in configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL, but how can I avoid the appDelegate's willPresentError to be called after that?

Comment: The NSPersistentDocument object isn't created so willPresentError can't be called. Did you implement appDelegate's `willPresentError:` or `application:willPresentError:`?

Comment: The appDelegate's one.

Comment: in my test app `application:willPresentError:` is called.

Comment: In mine too. The problem is: how to *prevent* it to be called? I have intercepted the error in configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL and replaced the default text, be now the appDelegate throw an unlocalized error: "The document could not be opened", so the problem is displaced, not solved.

Comment: You can replace the error in `application:willPresentError:`.

Comment: OK, it works now. I just don't catch the error in *configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL* at all and intercept it in the appDelegate. So I have only one error massage (of course the console is filled with messages but the user don't see them). Thanks a lot !